# odoo.tools.convert.ParseError: while parsing -> views.xml:15, near

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

Please let me know where I'm making mistake
I 'm trying to add a clickable Text, when click on that move to the form and tree view I can save data and when click on save button I can get back to the previous view, and the previous view then have a clickable text to go again and see the data

view.xml

```
    <odoo>
        <data>
    
            <record id="kts_project_task" model="ir.ui.view">
                <field name="name">kts.project.task.view.form</field>
                <field name="model">project.task</field>
                <field name="inherit_id" ref="project.view_task_form2" />
                <field name="arch" type="xml">
                    <field name="date_deadline" position="after">
                        <field name="actual_completion_date" />
                        <field name="testscript_ids"/>
                    </field>
                </field>
            </record>
 Error--->> <record id="kts_project_script" model="ir.ui.view">
                <field name="name">kts.project.task.testscript.view.form</field>
                <field name="model">kts.project.task.testscript</field>
                <field name="arch" type="xml">
                    <form string="Test Script">
                        <group col="2">
                               <group>
                                   <field name="test_case_id"/>
                                   <field name="test_priority"/>
                                   <field name="module_name"/>
                                   <field name="test_title"/>
                                   <field name="overall_status"/>
                               </group>
                               <group>
                                   <field name="test_designed_by"/>
                                   <field name="test_designed_date"/>
                                   <field name="test_executed_by"/>
                                   <field name="test_executed_date"/>
                                   <field name="remark"/>
                               </group>
                        </group>
                           <group>
                                <field name="pre_conditions"/>
                           </group>
                    </form>
                    <field name="test_script_line_ids" mode="tree">
                        <tree editable="bottom" string="Test Script" >
                            <field name="step_name" />
                            <field name="description" />
                            <field name="expected" />
                            <field name="actual_result" />
                            <field name="pass_fail"/>
                            <field name="remark"/>
                        </tree>
                    </field>
                </field>
            </record>
    
        </data>
    </odoo>
```

model.py

```
class kts_project_task(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'project.task'

    actual_completion_date = fields.Date(string='Actual Completion Date', index=True, copy=False, tracking=True)
    testscript_ids = fields.Many2one('kts.project.task.testscript', string="Test Script")



    @api.returns('self', lambda value: value.id)
    def copy(self, default=None):
        if default is None:
            default = {}
        default['user_id']=False
        return super(kts_project_task, self).copy(default)

    def get_user(self):
        if SUPERUSER_ID == self._uid:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    #field level readonly managed for users
    @api.model
    def fields_view_get(self, view_id=None, view_type='form', toolbar=False, submenu=False):
        res = super(kts_project_task, self).fields_view_get(view_id=view_id,
                                                  view_type=view_type,
                                                  toolbar=toolbar,
                                                  submenu=submenu)
        if self.env.user.has_group('project.group_task_user') :
            doc = etree.XML(res['arch'])
            for field in ['date_deadline','project_id','user_id','tag_ids','name', 'partner_id']:
                for node in doc.xpath("//field[@name='%s']" % field):
                    node.set("readonly", "1")
                    modifiers = json.loads(node.get("modifiers"))
                    modifiers['readonly'] = True
                    node.set("modifiers", json.dumps(modifiers))
            res['arch'] = etree.tostring(doc)
        return res


class kts_project_task_testscript(models.Model):
    _name = 'kts.project.task.testscript'

    test_case_id = fields.Char(string='Test Case ID')
    test_priority = fields.Char(string='Test Priority')
    module_name = fields.Char(string='Module Name')
    test_title = fields.Char(string='Test Title')
    overall_status = fields.Char(string='Overall Status')
    test_designed_by = fields.Char(string='Test Designed By')
    test_designed_date = fields.Date(string='Test Designed Date')
    test_executed_by = fields.Char(string='Test Executed By')
    test_executed_date = fields.Date(string='Test Executed Date')
    remark = fields.Char(string='Remarks')
    pre_conditions = fields.Text(string='Pre-conditions')
    test_script_line_ids = fields.One2many('kts.project.task.testscript.line', 'testscript_id', 'Test Script Id')


class kts_project_task_testscript_line(models.Model):
    _name = 'kts.project.task.testscript.line'

    step_name = fields.Char(string='Steps')
    description = fields.Text(string='Test Steps')
    expected = fields.Text(string='Excepted results')
    actual_result = fields.Text(string='Actual Results')
    pass_fail = fields.Selection([
        ('pass', 'Pass'),
        ('fail', 'Fail'),
    ], string="Status(P/F)")
    remark = fields.Text(string='Remarks')

    testscript_id = fields.Many2one('kts.project.task.testscript', string="Task Activities")
```

Comment: You should share full error log.

Comment: Thanks I found the solution, wrong container close

Comment: You have just to move the `test_script_line_ids` field inside the `form` tag.